# How can I use custom commands inside and outside maketitle with article class

Tags: titles

I´ve been using LaTeX for a while but I have zero experience creating macros or classes.

Basically what I want to do is to create commands like `\subject`, `\major` and `\college` and being able to use those commands in the title and in the headers/footers of an article class document.

I have been able to get the job done "manually" as shown in my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{A title}
\author{ an Author\\{\small a subject}\\\begin{footnotesize}
\textit{a College}
\end{footnotesize}}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{a Major}
\fancyhead[L]{an Author}
\fancyfoot[C]{Página \textbar \thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{a Subject}
\fancyfoot[L]{a Title}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{Página \textbar \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindtext
\blindlist{itemize}[5]
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

I want to make this a little more "automatic" just filling the labels like this:

```
\major{Mechanical Engineering}
```

This is the output
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at the title creation segment of the Latex wikibook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to define a command containing the text and to use it where needed.

```
\newcommand\major{Mechanical Engineering}
...
\fancyhead[R]{\major}
```

Definition and use needn't be in this textual order; `\major` has just to be defined before being used.

If you want to hide the definition of commands and do it similarly to `\author`, `\title` etc you need a bit of extra effort.

```
\newcommand\major[1]{\newcommand\themajor{#1}}
...
\major{Mechanical Engineering}
...
\fancyhead[R]{\themajor}
```

This code will give an error when `\themajor` is used before `\major`, or if `\major` is used twice. This seems to me like a feature, but if you want to avoid this, you can predefine `\themajor`.

```
\newcommand\themajor{}
\newcommand\major[1]{\renewcommand\themajor{#1}}
...
\major{Mechanical Engineering}
...
\fancyhead[R]{\themajor}
```

Note the use of `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`.